# Why process.env.JWT_EXPIRE is undefind? Nest js

Tags: nestjs, nest

Why process.env.JWT_EXPIRE is undefind?

```
 JwtModule.register({
      secret: jwtConstants.secret,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRE },
    }),
```

[Nest] 12700  - 09.04.2023, 05:06:30   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] "expiresIn" should be a number of seconds or string representing a timespan
Error: "expiresIn" should be a number of seconds or string representing a timespan

.env

```
JWT_EXPIRE=3600
```

auth.module.ts

```
  imports: [
    UsersModule,
    PassportModule.register({ session: true }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: jwtConstants.secret,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRE },
    }),
  ],
```

app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot(), AuthModule, UsersModule],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: JwtAuthGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Is the environment variable JWT_EXPIRE set in your .env file or your system environment variables?

Comment: Do you have something like `dotenv` loaded? Statements in the `.env` file are not real environment variables, so you need some kind of tool to have them show up in `process.env`

Comment: I installed dotenv and all working, thanks.

Comment: Actually the error suggests you might need to convert the value to a number with `parseInt`. Also if you don't tag people in replies, they will not get notified. I just happened to run into this question again.

Comment: use the async version of `JwtModule#register` and inject the config service into it to retrieve that env var loaded from `@nestjs/config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should install dotenv or install cross-env and use it in package.json like this:

`"start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=debug nest start --watch"`